# Using Debian as host for Virtualbox - problems with network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, bridge

I have been banging my head on this for awhile. Im somewhat new to using Debian as a host/router for virtual machines and Im strugeling to get remote access to my VMs.

My setup is like this:
Server connected directly to internet.
Server runs debian 9, and I have installed Virtualbox as host for VMs.

I have tried using bridge but with that I dont get internet on my VMs at all.
Using NAT in Virtualbox gives the VMs internet but Im not able to connect remotely directly to the VMs.
I have allso tried setting up a host-only interface in Virtualbox and adding this (vboxnet0) to the bridge but that didnt do anything.

What I want to achive is using the servers internet ip to connect too VMs in different ways (RDP/SSH/etc).
I think I need to find a way to forward connections to serverip:port to VMs ip:port but Im not having any luck.

Any help, suggestions or links to where to look for help would be highly appriciated.
And if it would be easyer or better using a different setup like ESXi to achive this, Im open for that aswell.

If any info is missing or incomplete, let me know and I'll supply it asap.